# Run batch script to run web pages in one window on pc start

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser

I have a batch script that I start with task scheduler on computer start. I need after running this script to show up some web pages that I don't have to do it again and again after every pc-start. But problem is that my script:

```
start "" http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d
start "" https://www.facebook.com/
start "" https://www.youtube.com/feed/history
```

Is naturally opening these links as three new browser windows, but I need all them to be tabs. Ok I was looking for solution but still did't found much.

But I found one great video that helped me push this problem further:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rcwz9CM9I_E

Where that guy have a script like:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BROWSER=firefox.exe
SET WAIT_TIME=2
START %BROWSER% -new-tab ""
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %WAIT_TIME% -w 1000 > nul
START %BROWSER% -new-tab ""
START %BROWSER% -new-tab ""
```

I know about this idea, but I have still problem with this. Browser will start web pages in one window but:

> - There is still problem that one page is in new second window, don't know why
> - I have there generated new empty tab that I won't

I am telling about this trying(I tried to get more time for example but not working well and much more combinations like this):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BROWSER=firefox.exe
SET WAIT_TIME=4

@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %WAIT_TIME% -w 1000 > nul

START "" http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d
START %BROWSER% -new-tab "" https://www.facebook.com/
START %BROWSER% -new-tab "" https://www.youtube.com/feed/history
```

Could someone please explain me how to do it programmatically and why it works so?

Comment: you can notice that example in youtube is very close to answer, but in his case there is still empty new tab that shouldn't be there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the command line,

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Browser
, Firefox accepts multiple urls to be opened together.

So the command would look like this:

```
START firefox.exe http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d  https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.youtube.com/feed/history
```

Comment: thats the exactly thing that I am talking about.... this is not working.. try to shut down whole firefox, all tabs you have opened... and try to run this script and you will see 3 new windows opened...

Comment: That's because you have three browsers opening a single tab. @loadingnow shows you how to open a single browser with three tabs. Replace `START "" http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d
START %BROWSER% -new-tab "" https://www.facebook.com/
START %BROWSER% -new-tab "" https://www.youtube.com/feed/history` with `START firefox.exe -new-tab http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d -new-tab https://www.facebook.com/ -new-tab https://www.youtube.com/feed/history`

Comment: Sorry @Rawns, but I replaced it with what you write here and stille 3 new windows are opened... did you even tried it? to close all browsers and tabs, wait a 2 second till process will be killed and rerun that script? because nothing that you all posted here still not working (from programmaticall point of view)

Comment: Try removing all the -new-tab parts and reverting to default behavior: `START firefox.exe  http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d  https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.youtube.com/feed/history` That should work better.

Comment: Right, tested this and it works. You don't need the new tab command. This works: `START firefox.exe http://stackoverflow.com/users/6637228/marek-bern%c3%a1d https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.youtube.com/feed/history`

Comment: user @loadingnow please post your answer as your comment here because it works what you wrote... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would it not just be a lot easier to manually set the home pages to open directly in Firefox so they open in individual tabs, and then just have a scheduled task to launch Firefox rather than a batch file? That way, a single browser instance will just open when you log in and all your homepages will automatically appear in separate tabs. Plus it will be far easier to add new tabs in the future:

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe it would.. thanks for answer, but I rather preffer task scheduler... and this is not answer for my problem...